# Can I use recvmmsg for a TCP socket?

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, udp

I know `sendmmsg` is useful to send multiple messages on a TCP socket.

However, the documentation of [`recvmmsg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmmsg.2.html) doesn't say anything whether it can be used for a TCP socket.

**If yes, is the stream byte order still guaranteed to be kept?**

Any documentation/citation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, `recvmsg` can be used for TCP streams. And yes, the order of the data received will be the same order as sent.

Comment: Could you refer me to the documentation?

Comment: From the `recvmmsg` manual: "The `recvmmsg()` system call is an extension of [`recvmsg(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) ..." And from the `recvmsg` manual: "The `recv()`, `recvfrom()`, and `recvmsg()` calls are used to receive messages from a socket.  They may be used to receive data on both connectionless and **connection-oriented** sockets." (emphasis mine). TCP sockets are "connection-oriented sockets". you could consider a single call to `recvmmsg` as multiple calls to `recvmsg`.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. This should be the answer.